# Where and how do I set the correct encoding when uploading files using xhr

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, multipartform-data

I am uploading image files, and I need them to work with accented characters - so I have made everything use `UTF-8`.

I use this javascript function to upload them:

```
     $('#files').change(function(e) {
            var formData = new FormData();
            for (var i=0; i<this.files.length;i++){
                formData.append(this.files[i].name, this.files[i]);
            }
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
                if ( 4 == this.readyState ) {
                    showMessage("Uploaded.");
                }
            };
            xhr.open('post', 'accoms/upload.jsp', true);
            xhr.send(formData);
        }, false);
```

So if I have a file named "Björk.jpg" for example, when I look at what gets sent to the server using FireFox Firebug it shows as:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="BjÃ¶rk.jpg"; filename="BjÃ¶rk.jpg"
```

and that seems to be what the server receives.

The encoding for the post shows as this:

```
Content-Type    text/html;charset=UTF-8
```

When I send regular form data input text in other forms, it sends, and the server receives, the word "Björk" correctly.

Here is the server-side code in case its that:

```
mpp=new MultipartParser(request, 100000000);
com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.Part part;
FilePart fp=null;
String fileName="";
files=new ArrayList();
while((part=mpp.readNextPart())!=null){
    if (part.isFile()){
        fp=(FilePart)part;
        fileName=fp.getFileName();
        File file=new File(fileName);
        long size=fp.writeTo(file);
                    files.add(file);
            }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parser uses its own encoding as is evident from the [API reference](http://www.servlets.com/cos/javadoc/com/oreilly/servlet/multipart/MultipartParser.html).

Try:

```
mpp = new MultipartParser(request, 100000000);
mpp.setEncoding("UTF-8");
//rest of your code
```

The reference recommends passing it in constructor though:

```
mpp = new MultipartParser(request, 100000000, true, true, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set encoding like this

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", url, true);
// retrieve data unprocessed as a binary string
oReq.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
```

Some more info can be found here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Thanks, I did try that by adding xhr.overrideMimeType("multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8"); but the encoding was already UTF-8 as seen in the headers in FireBug

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely in your server-side code.  Perhaps you are not taking into account that the filename is UTF-8 encoded.  Nothing you posted in your question suggests that the name is being sent incorrectly.  What you see in Firebug is not necessarily what is being sent.  It's very possible that the default encoding being used by Firebug when examining the request does not match the encoding in use by the browser.  This would explain why the filename looks garbled in Firebug.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I did consider that, so I output the filenames to the console as they are appended, and they look ok, ie. firebug console displays them correctly, but in the post params they are not correct.  On the server I am receiving correctly when its regular posted params from a regular form.  Also on the server side I have tried decoding as UTF-8 but its just more garbled.

Comment: Please show your server-side code.  The problem most likely lies there.

Comment: I am using com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.* to get the parts on the server which I do not use for regular forms, so I guess I'll check them to see what they are doing.

Comment: Yikes.  Why don't you just use [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/)?  That would be my choice.  Regardless, it seems likely that you are simply not decoding the parameters correctly server-side.

Comment: I've added the server-side code, I'll take a look at the FileUpload too thanks.

Comment: also, adding a decoder makes no difference fileName=URLDecoder.decode(fp.getFileName(),"UTF-8");

Comment: Thanks, you were right, I'll probably replace it with the lib you mentioned.