# Save binary data uploaded through AJAX on PHP server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, binary

I've read a `.png` image file into an Array Buffer.

```
var readSingleFile = function(e) {
          var file = e.target.files[0];
          if (!file) {
            return;
          }
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function(e) {
            var contents =new Int8Array(e.target.result);

            $.ajax({
                   url: 'saveBinaryData.php',
                   type: 'POST',
                   contentType: 'application/octet-stream', 
                   data: contents,
                   processData: false
                }); 
          };
          reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        }
```

This is posted to a PHP file as the AJAX describes.

How do I convert this binary data to an image format?

My code so far:

```
<?php
 if($data=file_get_contents($_POST)){
   echo "Error! Data not read!";
   return;
  }

  $data = imagecreatefromstring($data);

  var_dump($data);

  file_put_contents("recentImage1.png", $data);
  ?>
```

These are taken from various solutions found in Google.  The image file is created but does not hold any content and therefore cannot be opened.

Comment: Did you try to write the uploaded data directly into file? I think it should not need any conversion on server side. It least that's how I upload images via AJAX (but maybe I use a different library).

Comment: Yeah, that was the first thing I did - no joy. I had a look at `imagecreatefromstring()` afterwards.

Comment: `file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in /var/www/html/mqttHandscan/saveBinaryData.php` - taken from the Apache2 error log

Comment: It's because you convert the file to array. Instead, you should convert it to string or URL: look for `readAsDataURL()` or `readAsBinaryString()`

Comment: `var_dump($data)` is returning `NULL`.  Looks like it can't read the file contents uploaded.

Comment: When you read binary POSTed data, use `file_get_contents('php://input')` instead of accessing `$_POST`.

Answer (score 3):

This is simple working demo that saves the uploaded file:

JS:

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js'></script>
<script>upload = function() {
    f = new FileReader();
    f.onload = function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '?upload',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8',
            data: e.target.result.split(",", 2)[1], //remove text header
            processData: false
        });
    };

    f.readAsDataURL($('input')[0].files[0]);
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="file" />
<button onclick="upload()">Upload</button>
```

And PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['upload'])) {
    $file = file_get_contents('php://input');
    file_put_contents('recentImage1.png', base64_decode($file));
}
```

*All the code is in single file, just split into 3 parts for better formatting.*

Used posts:

- [Save binary data uploaded through AJAX on PHP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861803/save-binary-data-uploaded-through-ajax-on-php-server?noredirect=1#comment61291573_36861803)
- [file_get_contents(“php://input”) or $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731297/file-get-contentsphp-input-or-http-raw-post-data-which-one-is-better-to)
- [fileReader.readAsBinaryString to upload files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431365/filereader-readasbinarystring-to-upload-files)
- [Where and how do I set the correct encoding when uploading files using xhr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955159/where-and-how-do-i-set-the-correct-encoding-when-uploading-files-using-xhr)